# Piecewise Inverses?

Tags: functions

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x, & \text{if } x\leq 0 \\ 6x+x^2, & \text{if } x>0
\end{cases}$$

I have no trouble finding inverses of regular functions, but I'm not entirely confident about doing the same for piecewise functions.

I'm leaning towards just finding the inverse of each case, but I can't seem to find any information regarding this...

Is it as simple as I think it is?

Comment: Note that pos x -> pos $f(x)$, neg x -> neg $f(x)$ so if you have $f(x)=y$, then if $y$ is pos, so is $x$ and you can invert that term and similarly for negative.

Comment: It is as simple as you think, in this particular case where $f(x)$ is a bijection $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.  In other cases it may not be

Comment: I'd try that and see if $f(f^{-1}(x))=f^{-1}(f(x))=x$.